# How can I display a BufferedImage in a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, bufferedimage

I want to display variations of the same image in the same JFrame, for example display an image in JFrame, then replace it with gray scale of the same image.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will have to repaint the `JFrame` whenever you update the image.

Here is what a simple google on the topic brings up: (I use those tutorials for all my Java coding)

[Java Tutorial: Drawing an Image](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/drawimage.html)

Answer (score 50):

To build on camickr's solution (for the lazy like me who want quick code to copy/paste) here's a code illustration:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
frame.getContentPane().add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img)));
frame.getContentPane().add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img2)));
frame.getContentPane().add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img3)));
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
//frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // if you want the X button to close the app
```

Comment: This just makes the smallest window possible.

Comment: It's been a long time since I used swing, but i'd guess you didn't call `pack()` if you have a tiny window

Comment: exactly what i was looking for, quickly check whether bufferedImages are read correctly .. no need for all this JComponent extending and print overriding. Thanks!

Comment: @IanWill you will also need to call `frame.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(int width, int height));` before calling `frame.pack();` importing java.awt.Dimension also works too :) Also this should be the selected answer. +1 for code example.

Answer (score 5):

Just incase life's to short too read the official docs here's a dirty way to get it done multiple times over

```
private static JFrame frame;
private static JLabel label;
public static void display(BufferedImage image){
   if(frame==null){
       frame=new JFrame();
       frame.setTitle("stained_image");
       frame.setSize(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
       frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       label=new JLabel();
       label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));
       frame.getContentPane().add(label,BorderLayout.CENTER);
       frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
       frame.pack();
       frame.setVisible(true);
   }else label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not really sure what you question is but if you have a BufferedImage then you simply create an ImageIcon using the image, then you add the icon to a JLabel and add the label to the GUI like any other component.

If you question is about how to create a gray scale, the I suggest you search the web using those terms as the search keywords, I'm sure you will find examples out there.