# Array of JLabel ImageIcon

Tags: java, arrays, jlabel, imageicon

I am attempting to create a game of Sudoku. I am wanting to use the JSwing API. So, I am using an array of JLabels to display the grid. I have a picture drawn of a 3x3 grid, and I would like to display that in a 3x3 grid. My problem is it will not display the image. Can someone help me resolve the problem?

My Current Code looks like this, split into two class.

**Main.class**

```
package com.brendenbunker;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Main{

    FileMaker fileMaker;

    void init() {
        fileMaker = new FileMaker();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        ScreenGenerator gui = new ScreenGenerator();
        gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        double width = gui.gridPic.getIconWidth();
        double height = gui.gridPic.getIconHeight();
        int h = (int) height*4;
        int w = (int) width*3;

        gui.setSize(w,h);
        gui.setTitle("Suduko");
        gui.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

**ScreenGenerator.class**

```
package com.brendenbunker;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class ScreenGenerator extends JFrame{

    //Intro Components
    //JLabel temp;
    JLabel[] gridLabel;
    ImageIcon gridPic;
    //intro Vars


    public ScreenGenerator() {

        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        gridPic = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Grid_Unified.png"));
        gridLabel = new JLabel[8];

        for (int i=0; i>=9; i++) {
            gridLabel[i] = new JLabel("Hello");
        }

        for (int i=0; i>=9; i++) {
            gridLabel[i].setIcon(gridPic);
            add(gridLabel[i]);
        }

    }
}
```

All helped Appericiated

Comment: check your for loop...it will never enter into loop..so no need to check any other example..this is absolutely working..just you have to change the condition of `for(..;..;..)` loop...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change you for loop, it will not enter into loop as per your condition.

change loop to this..

```
    for (int i=0; i<8; i++) {
        gridLabel[i] = new JLabel("Hello");
    }

    for (int i=0; i<8; i++) {
        gridLabel[i].setIcon(gridPic);
        add(gridLabel[i]);
    }
```

it will work..

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.brendenbunker;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class ScreenGenerator extends JFrame{

    //Intro Components
    //JLabel temp;
    JLabel[] gridLabel;
    ImageIcon gridPic;
    //intro Vars


    public ScreenGenerator() {

        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        gridPic = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Grid_Unified.png"));
        gridLabel = new JLabel[8];

        //for (int i=0; i>=9; i++) {
            //gridLabel[i] = new JLabel("Hello");
       // }

        for (int i=0; i>=9; i++) {
            gridLabel[i] = new JLabel(gridPic);
            add(gridLabel[i]);
        }

    }
}
```

if you need icon then use the above code if you want text and icon then the following change will help you

```
gridLabel[i] = new JLabel("hello", gridPic, JLabel.CENTER);
```

hopefully that help

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this: [Displaying Image in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14353302/displaying-image-in-java)

I used to program in Java. I have moved on to Python but I remember many difficulties with this! Use the IO file system to display it. You will find examples here.

Correct me if I am wrong, this is Java?