# Converting audio file to create an Image, and converting audio file into a format usable by class Picture

Tags: java, image-processing, audio, visualization, javasound

I have to write a program in Java that uses [StdAudio](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/StdAudio.java.html) and [Picture](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/Picture.java.html) to create a two-dimensional color visualization of a sound file while it is playing but I'm not really sure how to.

Can someone tell me everything that I need or tell me what I need to do to "convert" the sound file so that it's readable by Picture?

I could grab the samples from the sound file and return them as array of doubles, but then how would that even create an image?  How could those values even sync with the image?

I have been playing around in eclipse just trying to figure out how this could possibly even work but my code just ends up being a whole mess.

```
private final static int SAMPLE_RATE = 44100;
private static int WIDTH = 500;
private static int HEIGHT = 100;


private static JFrame frame;
private static Picture pic;


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    pic = new Picture(WIDTH, HEIGHT); // <- blank black image
    String audioFile = "SampleTest2.wav";   
    double[] audio = StdAudio.read(audioFile);


    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setContentPane(pic.getJLabel());
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setTitle("Sound Visualization"); 
    frame.setResizable(false); 
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

    for (int k = 0; k < audio.length; k++)
        StdAudio.play(audio[k]);

    for (int i = 0; i < pic.width(); i ++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < pic.height(); j++)
        {
            pic.set(i, j, toColor(audio[SAMPLE_RATE + i]));
            //frame.setContentPane(pic.getJLabel());
        }   
        frame.repaint();
    }
}

private static Color toColor(double colVal)
{
    int r = (int) (((colVal + 1) / 2) * 255);
    int g = (int) (((colVal + 1) / 2) * 255);
    int b = (int) (((colVal + 1) / 2) * 255);
    return new Color(r, g, b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To use `StdAudio` you need `wav` file with sampling rate of `44100`. It means every second of this sound consists of 44100 values(samples). When you load such file with duration of 1 second using method `double[] read(String filename)` you will obtain an array with 44100 elements. Javadoc of that method tells us the values will be `between -1.0 and +1.0`. We can iterate over every sample, map values from -1..1 range to 0..255 range (because colors need values from 0 to 255) and paint each pixel with this color. For better effect let's not paint single pixel but a column of 100 pixels.
I'll create image of 500x100. It will display only 500 samples so it will represent 500/44100 = only 0,01 of a second. To create empty picture of that size use:

```
Picture p = new Picture(500, 100);
```

To paint separate pixels along the image use:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    p.set(i, 0, color);
}
```

and to display this picture use:

```
    p.show();
```

Next, to create a color we need 3 values: red, green and blue components. Here we have only one value so the resulting image will be a greyscale image because saturation of every component will be the same value `new Color(value, value, value)`. To quickly convert a range from -1..1 to 0..255 use such formula: `(int) (((d + 1) / 2) * 255)`

I used the first sound file from this site:
http://www.music.helsinki.fi/tmt/opetus/uusmedia/esim/index-e.html and the image I obtained is:
[image]

The code I used is:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.io.IOException;

public class StackOverflow58899141 {

    private static int IMAGE_WIDTH = 500;
    private static int IMAGE_HEIGHT = 100;

    static String filename = "O:\\1.wav";

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
        // reading sound file to samples
        double[] samples = StdAudio.read(filename);
        // creating empty image
        Picture p = new Picture(IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT);
        // filling image from left to right
        for (int i = 0; i < IMAGE_WIDTH; i++) {
            // filling image from top to bottom
            for (int j = 0; j < IMAGE_HEIGHT; j++) {
                // adding 44100 to skip 1s of silence at the beginning
                p.set(i, j, doubleToColor(samples[44100 + i]));
            }
        }
        p.show();
    }

    // convert number from range -1.0..1.0 to 0..255
    private static Color doubleToColor(double d) {
        int val = (int) (((d + 1) / 2) * 255);
        return new Color(val, val, val);
    }
}
```

Now you have a solid start to understand how it works. Although `Picture` class allows easy saving of an image it doesn't allow animating. To achieve that you'd need to [create own JFrame and draw image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14353302/displaying-image-in-java) and delay drawing each column of pixels to get the animation effect.

Comment: Okay so I did have the right idea.  I had for(int i = 0; i < pic.width; i++) and for(int j = 0; j < pic.height; j++) and stuff. I'll add the rest of my code later when I get on my computer.  Anyways, I mainly had trouble with converting the array of double values to rgb values.  Also I had no idea why the pixels weren't changing or moving around while the sound is playing.

Comment: Playing the sound and animating at the same time are two different tasks. It can be done, but the synchronization is up to you because there's no way to tell which fragment is currently played except counting elapsed time.

Comment: Also, if read() returns array values between -1 and +1, how come when I print out each values in the array, some of the values are less than -1 and greater than 1? I've seen a value that is 9.0000074782828364E-5 or whatever

Comment: 9.0000074782828364E-5 (note `E-5`) means 9.0000074782828364×10^(-5) so it's 0.000090000074782828364   
If you like the answer remember to [mark it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: And by the way, a method `play()` in `StdAudio` has nice protection for invalid values:
`if (sample < -1.0) sample = -1.0;` and `if (sample > +1.0) sample = +1.0;`

Comment: When you said "create own JFrame and draw image", does that mean I have to use save() from Picture class and save multiple pictures of different colors and use those images to draw in the JFrame?

Comment: No, saving creates a file and we don't need that. It's sufficient to keep image representation in memory. When you create a JFrame you can add JLabel containing your image. You can get it from Picture like this: `p.getJLabel()`.

Comment: I have now created a JFrame, but I still can't make the color go in sync with the sound.  I have added my code above.